# Invent With Python Transposition Cipher Decryption Error - Python

Tags: python, encryption

I'm having an issue with the code provided by the book (it is easily accessible online - Invent With Python, Transposition Decryption). The strange thing is, I can't find any information anywhere online about this error. I thought if it was an error in a public book like this at least one other person would have mentioned it.

So I'm wondering if I broke it somehow, even though all I really did was comment out the references to the 'pyperclip' script that was included with the code.

The original error was on line "numOfColumns = int(math.ceil(len(message) / key))" and later "plaintext = [''] * numOfColumns" as it was trying to multiply by a floating point and type errors didn't like that. I also think maybe this solution is potentially breaking it.

For reference, the output of this code is meant to print "Common sense is not so common.|"

```
# Transposition Cipher Decryption
# http://inventwithpython.com/hacking (BSD Licensed)

import math

def main():
    myMessage = 'Cenoonommstmme oo snnio. s s c'
    myKey = 8

    plaintext = transpositionDecryptMessage(myKey, myMessage)

    # Print with a | (called "pipe" character) after it in case
    # there are spaces at the end of the decrypted message.
    print(plaintext + '|')

    #pyperclip.copy(plaintext)


def transpositionDecryptMessage(key, message):
    # The transposition decrypt function will simulate the "columns" and
    # "rows" of the grid that the plaintext is written on by using a list
    # of strings. First, we need to calculate a few values.

    # The number of "columns" in our transposition grid:
    numOfColumns = int(math.ceil(len(message) / key))
    # The number of "rows" in our grid will need:
    numOfRows = key
    # The number of "shaded boxes" in the last "column" of the grid:
    numOfShadedBoxes = (numOfColumns * numOfRows) - len(message)

    # Each string in plaintext represents a column in the grid.
    plaintext = [''] * numOfColumns

    # The col and row variables point to where in the grid the next
    # character in the encrypted message will go.
    col = 0
    row = 0

    for symbol in message:
        plaintext[col] += symbol
        col += 1 # point to next column

        # If there are no more columns OR we're at a shaded box, go back to
        # the first column and the next row.
        if (col == numOfColumns) or (col == numOfColumns - 1 and row >= numOfRows - numOfShadedBoxes):
            col = 0
            row += 1

    return ''.join(plaintext)


# If transpositionDecrypt.py is run (instead of imported as a module) call
# the main() function.
if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: Can't reproduce. This code does for me what you say it should do. What version of python are you using?

Comment: I'm not entirely sure, it was at university. I'm going to test it at home and see if it works. Thank you for letting me know it works as it should though.